# SNR of filter output

Tags: filters, noise, gaussian, snr, signal-power

I have a filter where the input is:

$$ x(t) = s(t) + w(t) $$
which is signal plus white Gaussian noise and the output is $y(t)$. If the impulse response of the filter is $h(t)$, then:

$$y(t) = s(t)*h(t) + w(t)*h(t)$$

I have given the following equation to calculate the SNR:

$$SNR = \frac{\int_{-\infty}^\infty|s(t)*h(t)|^2 dt}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty|w(t)*h(t)|^2 dt}$$

And in frequency domain, following the Parseval's theorem:

$$SNR = \frac{\int_{-\infty}^\infty|S(f)H(f)|^2df}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty|W(f)H(t)|^2 df}$$

I wonder how this represents the signal power and noise power at numerator and denominator, respectively? Cause it is more like calculating energy than power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty|s(t)*h(t)|^2 \,\mathrm dt$$

requires that this integral exists – and that requires, unless an infinite amount of the energy of $s$ is in $\ker((*h))$ (i.e. gets mapped to 0) that $s$ is an *energy signal*, not only a *power signal* (as you're probably used to dealing with). (An energy signal is exactly a signal that is magnitude-integrable.)

For that, defining SNR as quotient of energies makes sense. Also, your $S(f), H(f)$ are then energy spectral densities, instead of power spectral densities.

Problem: WGN is not an energy signal, and it's by definition not in the kernel of any deterministic filter. Therefore,

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty|w(t)*h(t)|^2 \,\mathrm dt$$

simply doesn't exist and the formula doesn't "work out", as it has a diverging denominator.

I can only guess where the formula came from, something like from the derivation of (average) power of a signal $\xi$ being $\lim\limits_{T\to\infty}\frac1T\int_{T/2}^{T/2} |\xi(t)|^2 \,\mathrm dt$, and then eager cancelation of the $\frac 1T$ from  denominator and numerator?